# Waiting for a file to load (onload JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, file, onload, wait, filereader

I want to read a text from a file and return it in a function. So here's the important part of my code:

```
        function getFileRequest(id, contentType, callback) {
        var val = "x";      

        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            var element = document.getElementById(id);

            var file = element.files[0]; 
            if(file != null) {      
                if(file.type.match("text/xml")){
                    var r;
                    r = new FileReader();

                    r.onload = function (e) {
                        val = e.target.result;                    

                    }                   
                    r.readAsText(file);
                }
                else
                    alert("Wrong file format");
            }

        } else {
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser.');
        }

        alert(val);
        if(val == null)
                return "";
            else
                return getRequestBody(id,contentType,val);  

    }
```

I want to pass the text to a variable called "val". But, as it seems to me at least, alert(val) is always showing default "x" because probably it's not waiting for onload function to be executed. Am I right at all? 
How can I get an access to that text then? Is there a way to wait for an excecution?

Comment: You can not treat an asynchronous action as synchronous.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course the alert isn't in the onload function, so it's called immediately.

You may do that :

```
        var val = "x";      
        //... code to load a file variable
        var r;
        r = new FileReader();

        r.onload = function (e) {
            val = e.target.result;  
            r.readAsText(file);
            alert(val);
        };
```

You cannot wait and stop the execution of your code, so the general idea is to defer it using a callback.

Supposing the code you show is really to be done in two parts, one doing file manipulation and the other one using it, it could be like this :

```
function fetchVal(callback) {
        var val = "x";      
        //... code to load a file variable
        var r;
        r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function (e) {
            val = e.target.result;  
            r.readAsText(file);
            callback(val);
        };  
}

fetchVal(function(val){
   alert(val);
   // use val
});
```

Comment: Well, of course, but what I want is to get this text outside of that onload function

Comment: Your onload function can call another function, but you can't just stop the execution.

Comment: So do you have any idea how I could actually get a file text and return it in a function in a place where alert(val) is now in my version?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand callbacks, but I edited my post with a bigger piece of my code, so you could see how I wanna use this val variable. To be honest I don't know how I could use callback and an example you've given. Even if I could use it somehow in a part you mared with a comment, I still need to get this value in a previous function.

Comment: To write javascript, you really need to understand the logic of asynchronous calls and callbacks. There is no other way to handle asynchronous operations, like file reading.

Comment: Excellent answer and very well explained... +1

Comment: I don't see how this would work. Docs say `onload` is fired *after* the read operation completes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) so it looks like the call to `readAsText()` will never happen if done *inside* the `onload` handler? At least that's what happened when I tried this snippet...