# Load txt file contents into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm trying to load the contents of a .txt file into a javascript variable so I can then manipulate them and write them onto a paragraph.

I've looked into multiple questions, multiple links and nothing does it. They either use jQuery, which I don't understand, or they log the contents into the console, so I can't manipulate them, or they simply post code that does not work.

I can't understand why I can't save the contents into a variable when said contents are a simple string!

If *fr.result* is a string, why can't I save it to *trades* ?

Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Read Text File</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" name="inputfile"
            id="inputfile">
            
    <p>Complete trade history:</p>
    <p id="history">Upload file first!</p>
    <br>

    <pre id="output"></pre>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var trades = "";
    document.getElementById('inputfile')
        .addEventListener('change', function() {
            
        var fr=new FileReader();
        fr.onload=function(){
            document.getElementById('output').textContent=fr.result;
            document.getElementById('history').textContent=typeof(fr.result);
            trades += fr.result;
        }
            
        fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
    })
    
    document.getElementById('history').textContent="history: " + trades;
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [`readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) is asynchronous and thus `trades` is *yet* `""` by the time you add it to **#history**. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090996/waiting-for-a-file-to-load-onload-javascript) might help you on your way.

Comment: @Lain yes it does, thank you!